# How can I use one variable's return value in an if/else statement for another variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I have a variable that returns a random value from an array full of different predictions for a fortune teller app, the code is below:

```
- (NSString *) randomPredictions {
    int random = arc4random_uniform(self.predictions.count);
    return [self.predictions objectAtIndex:random];
}
```

Now, I'm trying to make another variable that will change to color of the prediction's text. If a good fortune returns, the color will be green, but if a bad one returns, it'll be red.

The way I thought of doing it was to select the returned randomPrediction's position in the array, and check it against a set of indexes in the if statement. If it's one of the selected numbers, it gets one colors, otherwise it gets the other.

This as much as I know to code so far, but I know it's wrong and would appreciate some help:

```
- (NSString *) selectedColor {
    if (randomPredictions = objectAtIndexes:0,2,4,6) {
       return [UIColor greenColor]; 
    } else {
        return [UIColor redColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: UIColor isn't an NSString.

Comment: And what the heck is this supposed to mean: `randomPredictions = objectAtIndexes:0,2,4,6`??

Comment: A simpler way to do this would be to have the two types in separate lists; choose between the types first, then choose from the appropriate list.

Answer (score 1):

The simple and straight forward way.

```
NSUInteger index = [self.predictions indexOfObject:[self randomPredictions]];
if (index == 0 || index == 2 || index == 4 || index == 6) {
    return [UIColor greenColor]; 
} else {
    return [UIColor redColor]; 
}
```

The more complex, but more complete way

```
NSUInteger index = [self.predictions indexOfObject:[self randomPredictions]];
if (index == NSNotFound) { // Some error occurred!!!!
    return nil;
} else if (index % 2 == 0) { // All even number indexes are green.
    return [UIColor greenColor]; 
} else {
    return [UIColor redColor]; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea you could use the double pipes like that for statements.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you be better served by an array of dictionaries or Core Data, where multiple attributes like color, sound, and answer text could all be associated with the same key value/attribute value?

But if not, how about using a switch/case statement?

```
switch (index) {
    case :0
    case :2
    case :4
    case :6 {
       [UIColor redColor];
       break;
       }
    default: {
       [UIColor greenColor];
       break;
       }
}
```

the `case` statement allows the grouped cases to fall through since there is not a `break` associated with them.  So 0, 2, 4, and 6 all run the same code.  Everything else hits the default.  This would allow for some fortunes to be so-so and get a Yellow color, but including them after case 6 is completed and grouping them together under one break.

```
     case 10:
     case 11:
     case 12: {
         [UIColor yellowColor];
         break;
         }
```

I still like the dictionary or Core Data options, but this way is, I believe more flexible and maintainable.

P.S. Forgive any syntax errors.  I was coding on the fly and it is not tested.